# Best way to inherit tables with kotlin and jpa

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa

What is the best way to inherit jpa entity using kotlin
For example i have abstract entity `User` which looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class User (
  val password: String,
  var email: String
)
```

And i got second entity `PrivateUser` extended from `User`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "private_person")
class PrivatePerson(
    override var password: String,
    override var email: String,
    val name: String
) : User(password, email)
```

Actually i don't like to override every single property from super class. Maybe there's more elegant solution for that task.
Or is it the best way to work around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

Maybe you need something like that?

```
abstract class User (
        open val password: String = "",
        open var email: String = "")

class PrivatePerson(
        override var password: String,
        val name: String): User(password)
```

You have to have an initialized variable if you want to skip it.